# source RPM doesn't seem to install on CentOS with no errors

Tags: centos, rpm, docker

My experience with CentOS and RPM's is limited so I might be missing something obvious, but I can't seem to figure this out...  I'm trying to install Sphinx into CentOS 6 in a Docker image using the instructions here:  http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/installing-redhat.html  (though, I'm trying to install from the source RPM instead of the binary)

I run `docker run -i -t centos:centos6 bash` to get a CentOS image running and then here's what I get when trying to run the commands (slightly different than the instructions to give more information and skip prompts):

```
[root@db60006ae258 /]# yum -y install postgresql-libs unixODBC
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
base                                                                                                               | 3.7 kB     00:00     
base/primary_db                                                                                                    | 4.6 MB     00:37     
extras                                                                                                             | 3.4 kB     00:00     
extras/primary_db                                                                                                  |  34 kB     00:00     
updates                                                                                                            | 3.4 kB     00:00     
updates/primary_db                                                                                                 | 3.3 MB     00:08     
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package postgresql-libs.x86_64 0:8.4.20-4.el6_7 will be installed
---> Package unixODBC.x86_64 0:2.2.14-14.el6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libltdl.so.7()(64bit) for package: unixODBC-2.2.14-14.el6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libtool-ltdl.x86_64 0:2.2.6-15.5.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

==========================================================================================================================================
 Package                              Arch                        Version                              Repository                    Size
==========================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 postgresql-libs                      x86_64                      8.4.20-4.el6_7                       updates                      202 k
 unixODBC                             x86_64                      2.2.14-14.el6                        base                         378 k
Installing for dependencies:
 libtool-ltdl                         x86_64                      2.2.6-15.5.el6                       base                          44 k

Transaction Summary
==========================================================================================================================================
Install       3 Package(s)

Total download size: 624 k
Installed size: 1.8 M
Downloading Packages:
(1/3): libtool-ltdl-2.2.6-15.5.el6.x86_64.rpm                                                                      |  44 kB     00:00     
(2/3): postgresql-libs-8.4.20-4.el6_7.x86_64.rpm                                                                   | 202 kB     00:00     
(3/3): unixODBC-2.2.14-14.el6.x86_64.rpm                                                                           | 378 kB     00:01     
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                                                                     234 kB/s | 624 kB     00:02     
warning: rpmts_HdrFromFdno: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, key ID c105b9de: NOKEY
Retrieving key from file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
Importing GPG key 0xC105B9DE:
 Userid : CentOS-6 Key (CentOS 6 Official Signing Key) <centos-6-key@centos.org>
 Package: centos-release-6-7.el6.centos.12.3.x86_64 (installed)
 From   : /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
  Installing : libtool-ltdl-2.2.6-15.5.el6.x86_64                                                                                     1/3 
  Installing : unixODBC-2.2.14-14.el6.x86_64                                                                                          2/3 
  Installing : postgresql-libs-8.4.20-4.el6_7.x86_64                                                                                  3/3 
  Verifying  : postgresql-libs-8.4.20-4.el6_7.x86_64                                                                                  1/3 
  Verifying  : unixODBC-2.2.14-14.el6.x86_64                                                                                          2/3 
  Verifying  : libtool-ltdl-2.2.6-15.5.el6.x86_64                                                                                     3/3 

Installed:
  postgresql-libs.x86_64 0:8.4.20-4.el6_7                                 unixODBC.x86_64 0:2.2.14-14.el6                                

Dependency Installed:
  libtool-ltdl.x86_64 0:2.2.6-15.5.el6                                                                                                    

Complete!
[root@db60006ae258 /]# rpm -Uhvv http://sphinxsearch.com/files/sphinx-2.2.10-1.rhel6.src.rpm
Retrieving http://sphinxsearch.com/files/sphinx-2.2.10-1.rhel6.src.rpm
D: ============== /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.Knfx7x
D: loading keyring from pubkeys in /var/lib/rpm/pubkeys/*.key
D: couldn't find any keys in /var/lib/rpm/pubkeys/*.key
D: loading keyring from rpmdb
D: opening  db environment /var/lib/rpm cdb:mpool:joinenv
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Packages rdonly mode=0x0
D: locked   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Packages
D: opening  db index       /var/lib/rpm/Name rdonly mode=0x0
D:  read h#     155 Header sanity check: OK
D: added key gpg-pubkey-c105b9de-4e0fd3a3 to keyring
D: Using legacy gpg-pubkey(s) from rpmdb
D: Expected size:      4201741 = lead(96)+sigs(180)+pad(4)+data(4201461)
D:   Actual size:      4201741
D: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.Knfx7x: Header SHA1 digest: OK (f86024cbd050d0758ddb1aa0fc73c246deeb2f90)
D:  added source package [0]
D: found 1 source and 0 binary packages
D: Expected size:      4201741 = lead(96)+sigs(180)+pad(4)+data(4201461)
D:   Actual size:      4201741
D: InstallSourcePackage at: psm.c:244: Header SHA1 digest: OK (f86024cbd050d0758ddb1aa0fc73c246deeb2f90)
D: created directory(s) /root/rpmbuild mode 0755
D: created directory(s) /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES mode 0755
D: created directory(s) /root/rpmbuild/SPECS mode 0755
   1:sphinx                 D: ========== Directories not explicitly included in package:
D:          0 /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/
D:          1 /root/rpmbuild/SPECS/
D: ==========
warning: user builder does not exist - using root
warning: group builder does not exist - using root
D: fini      100644  1 (   0,   0)       288 /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/config.patch;56a3c57f unknown
warning: user builder does not exist - using root
warning: group builder does not exist - using root
D: fini      100664  1 (   0,   0)    129584 /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/libstemmer_c.tgz;56a3c57f unknown
warning: user builder does not exist - using root
warning: group builder does not exist - using root
D: fini      100664  1 (   0,   0)   1064388 /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/re2.tar.gz;56a3c57f unknown
warning: user builder does not exist - using root
warning: group builder does not exist - using root
########################################### [100%]
D: fini      100644  1 (   0,   0)   3109250 /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/sphinx-2.2.10-release.tar.gz;56a3c57f unknown
warning: user builder does not exist - using root
warning: group builder does not exist - using root
D: fini      100644  1 (   0,   0)      2048 /root/rpmbuild/SOURCES/sphinx.init;56a3c57f unknown
warning: user builder does not exist - using root
warning: group builder does not exist - using root
D: fini      100644  1 (   0,   0)      9647 /root/rpmbuild/SPECS/sphinx_rel22.spec;56a3c57f unknown
GZDIO:     527 reads,  4316100 total bytes in 0.021979 secs
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Name
D: closed   db index       /var/lib/rpm/Packages
D: closed   db environment /var/lib/rpm
[root@db60006ae258 /]# service searchd start
bash: service: command not found
[root@db60006ae258 /]# find / -name "searchd*"
[root@db60006ae258 /]#
```

Comment: A source rpm is just that, the source code used to create the binary rpm.  You can't install the source rpm and run the program.  You have to either install the binary rpm or build the source rpm into your own binary rpm.

Comment: @Ciclamino - Thanks..  I assumed that it would compile the source for me and then install.  I've found how you need to use `rpmbuild`.  Feel free to put that as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

A source RPM (src.rpm) is source packaged up using the RPM format. You can use that to build a binary package for your machine, or use it as a starting point for custom versions. Source RPMs are quite a bit more portable than binary ones, but unless you are knowledgeable I'd advise against going down this path.

Check the CentOS pages, see if there are binary packages available for your system either as an official package or **in one of the vetted third party repositories**. Be careful, some more shady third party repositories overwrite core packages and could break your system (or make it hard to update).